# Handle multiple images and apply fixed width and height to avoid "jank" (Image elements do not have explicit width and height)

Tags: html, css, lighthouse

If we want to use different pictures of different sizes according to a screen break. What would be the best way to approach this?

For instance

```html
<picture class="image-wrapper">
    <source srcset="images/image-product-desktop.jpg" media="(min-width: 800px)"/>
    <img class="image" src="images/image-product-mobile.jpg" alt="chanel perfume bottle lying down with leaves draped around">
</picture>
```

The issue above is that I can provide height and width for the mobile image, but if the user loads on the desktop, I don't understand yet, how to provide fixed width for that. I should add that the two images will have a different art direction. They will not have the same intrinsic width or height.

I found an excellent SO post below which is relevant, but hasn't responded to this precise situation. Here it is for reference.

[Image elements do not have explicit width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65076805/image-elements-do-not-have-explicit-width-and-height)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so in my solution, I moved away from srcsets and used a div with a background image. The image displayed is decided by CSS.

To handle the jank... I started by finding the dimensions of my picture
eg.

Mobile image
Height = 240, Width = 343

Desktop Image
Height = 450, Width = 300

I then added this to the root as a var with calc()

```css
:root {
/* height / width * 100% (not width / height) */
  --mobile-aspect: calc(240 / 343 * 100%); 
  --desktop-aspect: calc(450 / 300 * 100%)
}
```

After adding padding-top to the future-images parent divs I added a media query

```css
.image-wrapper {
  padding-top: var(--mobile-aspect);
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("../images/image-product-mobile.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .image-wrapper {
    padding-top: var(--desktop-aspect);
    background-image: url("../images/image-product-desktop.jpg");
  }
}
```

At this point. No complaints from Light house and no jankiness! Hope this helps.

Great resources
[Clear Video description](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDGStz9TvxQ)
[In Depth CSS Tricks Article](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/)